# How to solve that ODE?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm am trying to solve the following differentia equation
$$
u'(x)=\frac{u(x)}{\sqrt{u^2(x)-\alpha^2}},
$$
where $\alpha$ is some non-zero real number. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Try separating variables.

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly, I have to find a primitive $F(u)$ of $\sqrt{u^2-\alpha^2}/u$, and then to invert $F$, right ? But that looks hard to me !

Comment: Try $u=a\cosh(z)$

Comment: You may not be able to find an explicit expression for $x$ in terms of $t$; you may only be able to find an implicit relationship between the two.